# How to set session timeout in ktor?

Tags: ktor

How to set the timeout after which if there is no user activity the session expires?
I am looking for something like in jetty:

```
ServletContextHandler webappContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
... 
webappContext.getSessionHandler().setMaxInactiveInterval(timeout_in_sec);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement that yourself, it depends on your Storage Manger. If you look at the simplest one

https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/master/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/jvm/src/io/ktor/sessions/SessionStorageMemory.kt

The sessions are stored in a concurrent map

```
private val sessions = ConcurrentHashMap<String, ByteArray>()
```

Instead you want something that will expire the sessions. For example you can use guava cache
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

```
private val engineCache: Cache<String, ByteArray> = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(50)
            .expireAfterAccess(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()
```